# How to add rules to OneLogin App via API?

Tags: onelogin

I'm trying to add AWS Accounts to OneLogin automatically. This by itself does work flawlessly using the API. Now I'd also like to add rules to the just-created app. This doesn't work at all. The endpoint only gives a 404 response. I can add rules for this app as I like within the UI.

[List Rules API doc](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/app-rules/list-rules) states that the URL scheme is `https://subdomain/api/2/apps/:app_id/rules`. Assuming my created app has the ID 2455, the URL should be `https://subdomain/api/2/apps/2455/rules`.

```bash
$ curl 'https://mycompany.onelogin.com/api/2/apps/2455/rules' -X GET -H "Authorization: bearer myTokenHere"
{"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Resource not found","statusCode":404}
```

Bluntly copying the sample from the [create-rule](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/app-rules/create-rule) API doc gives the same result.

```bash
$ curl 'https://mycompany.onelogin.com/api/2/apps/2455/rules' \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: bearer myTokenHere" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "name": "My Second Rule",
    "match": "all",
    "enabled": true,
    "position": null,
    "conditions": [
        {
            "source": "last_login",
            "operator": ">",
            "value": "90"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "action": "set_status",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ]
}'
{"name":"NotFoundError","message":"Resource not found","statusCode":404}
```

The connector ID is 30319 - Amazon Web Services (AWS) - SAML.

What am I doing wrong here?